# Difference between Oracle VM and Citrix XEN?

Tags: virtualization, xen, oracle-vm-server

I`ve been testing Oracle-VM this day. Is there anyone out there who has tested both XEN-based solutions?

What are the main differences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not many XEN-Folks out there. So I have to answer this myself.

Oracle-VM is basically a RedHat clone, stripped down to the barest rpms that are needed to drive a XEN-system. It has an elder, Open-source XEN-version.

Atop of that a big GUI running as application on Oracle Weblogic, which in turn needs an Oracle-DB (XE will do).

Citrix sports its own GUI, based on the newest (non-open) xen-version.

Comment: I would also recommend avoiding Oracle-VM if at all possible. Some things can only be done from the GUI, some only from the CLI, and the GUI and CLI are not aware of each other. Some critical things break in dumb ways if you do something in one and it's out of state with the other. Pretty much *any* other XEN platform will be better.

Comment: @bahamat that aside the GUI is painfully slow. Apart from that - if it would do the "correct" things in the background it is a nice approach. Everything is built with HA in mind - even on a one-node system. One way of using oracle-vm might be to throw away the GUI and do everything with your own scripts...